# IPython notebook embed postscript

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, postscript

How can we render postscript documents in IPython notebook?

I saw there is support for other file formats such as jpg, png, pdf and svg but couldn't find any mention about postscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostScript isn't a 'file format', its a programming language. In order to render PostScript you will need a complete PostScript interpreter.

Presumably you could write one in Python, the last time I saw an estimate for the amount of time required to write a full PostScript interpreter it was 5 man years, its probably a bit more now.

Or you could render the program externally using Ghostscript, to produce something you can already read. Since you say PDF is already supported it would seem sensible to convert to that instead; since its not a bitmap format you won't lose scalability.